Make a column in an interactive grid link column based on another column's value
I have a column LINK_YN whose value will be either 'Y' or 'N'. I have another column ITEM which needs to be a link column to page 5 only if LINK_YN is 'Y'. If LINK_YN is 'N' then ITEM should be displayed as plain text.
